# Running Same Step Multiple Times With Different Data In Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

Is there any way I could run the 'Given' step multiple times with the given data(Products and Statuses) before other steps are executed? I have tried below but it fails

```
Scenario Outline: Creating multiple products
 Given I have created multiple <products> that are at different <statuses> 
  Examples:
      |products   |  statuses     |
      |P1         |  In Progress  |
      |P1         |  Completed    |
      |P1         |  Stopped      |
    When I have navigated to products page
    Then I should see all products created
```

Answer (score 2):

U are mixing up the usage of Scenario Outline Examples and DataTable. The Examples table is placed below all the steps for a Scenario Outline.

You can use a DataTable instead and iterate it to create the objects.

```
Scenario: Creating multiple products
 Given I have created the following products 
      |products   |  statuses     |
      |P1         |  In Progress  |
      |P1         |  Completed    |
      |P1         |  Stopped      |
    When I have navigated to products page
    Then I should see all products created

@Given("I have created the following products")
public void createMultipleProducts(DataTable data) {
     //Iterate the data and create each product
}
```

Comment: JavaScript cucumber datatable:
'const rows= table.hashes() ;'
 ' console.log('status: ' + rows[0].statuses); ' would return _in progress_